# В чем заключается ошибка и как это исправить?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу передать данные из CSV файла в DataGridView. Написал класс для данных которые будут в таблице. Использовал библиотеку CSVHelper и вылезла такая ошибка.

```
        public class DataInfo
        {
            public string SurName { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public bool Working { get; set; }
        }
        public DataTable read(string filePath)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filePath));
            // Creating the columns
            typeof(DataInfo).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList().ForEach(x => dt.Columns.Add(x));

            // Adding the rows
            csv.GetRecords<DataInfo>().ToList.ForEach(line => dt.Rows.Add(line.Name, line.Age, line.Birthdate, line.Working));
            return dt;
```

Comment: Добавьте ошибку текстом.

Comment: Опечатка `csv.GetRecords<DataInfo>().ToList()...`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Dmitry, я скрин прикрепил там виден текст с ошибкой

Comment: Текст ошибки надо вставлять текстом, поисковые системы не умеют читать скриншоты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обращаешься к функции как к проперти.

Функции вызываются со скобками

`ToList` -> `ToList()`

А проперти - без.

Comment: О, спасибо! Работает

Comment: Зачем отвечать на опечатку?

Comment: @aepot потому что человек не видит разницы между методом и переменной класса. Собственно и в синтаксисе их использования. Это опечатка не со случайности а с незнания разницы